# How to set the number of mappers in new Hadoop api?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've switched to the new Hadoop api (mapreduce) from the old one (mapred). I can't set the number of mappers in the new api. I can use `job.setNumReduceTasks()` to set the number of reducers but there isn't any method for number of mappers. I also tried `conf.setInt("mapred.map.tasks", numMapper)` and `conf.setInt("mapreduce.map.tasks", numMapper)` but it is not working either.

Comment: I've seen this question come up a couple times and never have I seen a good reason to do this. Number of mappers = number of input splits sounds good to me.

Comment: I think the better and more appropriate question is "how do I change my input splits so that I have fewer?"

Answer (score 2):

The number of mapper tasks is determined by the **input split** you have. Obviously, each part will be processed by 1 mapper. So essentially, your data determines the number of your mappers!

You can however use `mapreduce.jobtracker.maxtasks.perjob` to limit the parallelism (unfortunately, this affects both mappers and reducers!). But if you set this to 10, at most 10 mappers should run in parallel.

A more fine-grained control would be nice, but is an open ticket:

> [MAPREDUCE-5583: Ability to limit running map and reduce tasks](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5583)

Comment: you mean there is no way to explicitly determine the number of mappers in the new api? as it is possible in the old api.

Comment: See the ticket I linked.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Hadoop 2.7, you can use `mapreduce.job.running.map.limit` and `mapreduce.job.running.reduce.limit` to control these at each job level.

Fixed by this [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5583).

Answer (score 0):

In YARN, one can set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize (its in megabytes) much higher than the blocksize of the files being read.  This will force more data through each mapper thereby reducing the number of mappers required.  However, some file formats may have their own minimum split size which takes priority over this setting.